# Как обеспечить работу нескольких приложений с одной базой данных MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql

Допустим, у меня есть несколько экземпляров одного и того же приложения, написанного на Java, которые подключаются к одной и той же базе данных mysql.
Возможно ли, что эта конструкция начнёт барахлить, если два или более приложений одновременно отправят запросы в базу данных?
Если да, то есть ли способ определить, занята ли бд выполнением какого-то запроса или свободна?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Корректнее задать вопрос: "Является ли MySQL многопользовательской базой данных? Как контролировать целостность данных?". Однозначно, да. MySQL позволяет сохранить целостность данных при условии использования определенных процедур. Судя по вашему вопросу, вам необходимо обратиться к документации по СУБД и учебным материалам. Рассмотрите вопросы индексов, ключей, связывания таблиц и транзакций.

В конечном итоге у вас на клиентском приложении и в процедурах сервера должна сложиться ситуация, при которой декларируется и обеспечивается порядок изменения данных.

Если рассмотреть ситуацию с простыми однозначными запросами, то "барахлить" ничего не будет, потому что СУБД делает большую часть работы по обеспечению целостности самостоятельно.

В случае комбинированных или зависимых запросов, например, когда результат выборки зависит от только что внесенных данных, и при этом необходимо исключить случай внесения изменений другим пользователем (процедурой) в момент исполнения такого пакетного задания, используются [транзакции](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).

Конечно, это не исчерпывающий ответ, но, надеюсь, это поможет.

Comment: В дополнение ответ в этой же ветке http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420054/178725

Answer (score 1):

просмотреть информацию о том, мешают ли приложения друг другу можно через механизм блокировок в БД, почитайте об этом, вот тут https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html , также возможны проблемы с ресурсами, это этого надо просматривать общуую нагрузку на сервер БД и кол-во свободных, коннектов, блокировок, памяти, cpu...